Reference Request For Fundamental Lemma of Weight Theory
I am attempting to find a particular paper that gives a proof of the following fundamental lemma.

Let $\varphi$ be a lower semicontinuous weight (so $\varphi(a) \leq \liminf_i \varphi(a_i)$ for $a_i \rightarrow a$) on a $\mathrm{C}^{*}$-algebra $A$ and define $\mathcal{F} := \{\omega \in A^{*}_{+} |  \omega \leq \varphi\}$.  Then $\varphi(a) = \sup_{\omega \in \mathcal{F}} \omega(a)$ for all $a \in A_{+}$.

There is apparently a proof of this fact in ‘Poids sur une $C^{*}$-algebrè’ by F. Combes, however I can’t find this text anywhere online and it isn’t even in English.
I really would appreciate if someone could either point me to an English source that has this result, or if someone could provide a proof of this result so I can look over it.
Thank you.

The two properties are actually equivalent. This was proven in

U. Haagerup, Normal Weights on W$^*$-Algebras, JFA 19 (1975), 302-318.

A detailed account appears as Theorem 1.3 in Stratila's Modular Theory in Operator Algebras.
The proof is not particularly hard, but it still takes several pages, even for just the implication you want.
